# Do you need to migrate to Drive API when using https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

The 22nd of January, I received an email with the subject 'Important: Steps to migrate from discontinued Documents List API' from Google Apps  .

> Important: Steps to migrate from discontinued Documents List API
>
> Hello administrators,
>
> We recently [communicated](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/12/reminder-to-migrate-to-updated-google.html) that Documents List API will be discontinued on April 20, 2015. This change means that service calls for this API will no longer be supported, and any Google Apps features that are implemented using this API will no longer function.
>
> Our records indicate that you may have an application that uses Documents List API, and we recommend that you migrate to Drive API, which has [comparable
>   functionality](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j-eDNShUksN81dfpUjHLsYs3mYKzm-NcRETa28PqvTQ/pubhtml#), as soon as possible.
>
> Here's what you need to do:
>
> Determine if you have an application that makes requests to these
>   types of URLs:
>
> - https://docs.google.com/feeds/
> - https://docs.googleusercontent.com/
> - https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/
>
> Migrate the applications to [Drive
>   API](https://developers.google.com/drive/). If you have questions
>   about migration, please contact Google Apps for Work Support.
>
> Sincerely, The Google Apps for Work Team

I think it says that applications using https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/ should migrate to the new Drive API. But in the new Drive API, this URL is used too:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#sheets_api_urls_visibilities_and_projections

Is there a typo somewhere in the URL either in the email or Drive API documentation?
Or is this email saying that when you determined you used any of these URL's you're OK?

*PS: I opened a case at Google but I fear a late response, so I asked here.*

Comment: Great question, this is very confusing indeed.

Comment: check status of at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758813

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is no.

The Docslist API is being discontinued because it has been replaced by the Drive API. In the case of the Spreadsheet API, there is no replacement API (yet - maybe one day), so it remains supported.

The only gotcha is that at some point, only OAuth 2 will be supported for authentication/authorisation so if you're using OAuth 1 or u/p, you have some work to do.

Comment: And concerning the 3 URLs mentioned in the email. How should I read those. When your app's using them should you or should you not migrate to Drive API?

Comment: If you are using any of the url's listed then you need to migrate.

Comment: @DaImTo something looks wrong ... that contradicts what pinoyyid said. pinoyyid said the API will remain. The issue is both APIs include this url https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/ but it looks like only one API is being shut down. Just looking to confirm the other API in unaffected.

Comment: I understand the ambiguity. I'm basing my opinion on the fact that the docslist API page at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/ clearly shows the deprecation and EOL.The spreadsheet API at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ has no equivalent notice, nor has it ever had.

Comment: Ok I agree its confusing. Going to find someone at Google to ask

Comment: Confirmed that the email was misleading with regard to the Sheets API. It is not yet deprecated. More details about what is actually shutting down in April can be found at the Apps Developer Blog - http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/12/reminder-to-migrate-to-updated-google.html

Comment: I'm not sure to clearly understand: we are suppose to migrate to Drive API for what? Yes, I know document list API will be discontinued soon, but how are we suppose to do it? And if we are only using spreadsheet API, that's not necessary?

Comment: @AnthonyLiard you ask 3 questions. 1/ I don't understand the question. 2/ how are you supposed to do what? 3/ you are correct that the Spreadsheet API is not deprecated so you have no need to migrate (in fact there is nothing to migrate to)

Comment: @pinoyyid 1. What does drive API contains? 2. In this documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/web/migration, it's just talking about scope for the migration from Documents List API, do we only have to change the scope? 3. thank you

Comment: @AnthonyLiard On SO you should really be asking individual questions, usually with code samples. it's not a great idea to hijack the comments of an answer to ask additional questions.

Comment: @pinoyyid better? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749569/whats-the-difference-between-google-document-list-api-and-google-drive-api

Answer (score 1):

The official Google response is that the Spreadsheets API will continue to function after the 20 April shutdown:

"Apologies for the confusing email. The sheets API is not yet deprecated and will continue to operate beyond the April shutdowns."

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3709