# Notification about deprecated DocumentList API requires check of spreadsheet links

Tags: java, gdata, google-sheets-api

I have received a notification that DocumentList API will be deprecated this month:

> **Here's what you need to do:**
>
> Determine if you have an application that makes requests to these types of URLs:
>
> - https://docs.google.com/feeds/
> - https://docs.googleusercontent.com/
> - https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/
>
> Migrate the applications to Drive API.

I don't understand why I need to check spreadsheet links - I am using them with Google Sheets API 3.0 in Java (those links are also in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20) and are not deprecated)

I have changed the authentication to OAuth 2.0 (from Client Login) on this API.

Do I need to make other changes to Google Sheets API? (I don't want problems after the DocumentList API removal.)

Comment: Hopefully this would answer your questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169309/do-you-need-to-migrate-to-drive-api-when-using-https-spreadsheets-google-com-f and https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3709

Comment: Thanks! It should be OK.